# Loop through Names and add 1 to Name, if already found

Tags: python, loops, abaqus

This is an Abaqus application of a Python scripting but still a general question that doesn't require Abaqus knowledge.

Im no programmer and lack this necessary kind of thinking so would be very grateful for a help.

I have a database containing something called **step names**. I want to create an entity, which is a step too (**a new step**). If such name exists already, I want the script to add +1 to the name. If that one exists, I want it to add another +1 and so on.

Nothing important so far, just importing:

```
# importing some libraries
from abaqus import *
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import visualization
import fileinput
import os
from odbAccess import *
from textRepr import *
```

Now we open the file:

```
odb_path="analysis6.odb"
my_odb=session.openOdb(name=odb_path,readOnly=FALSE)
# based upon our knowledge of the database, will be automated later
lastStep="loading step"
```

Lets automate some name-sourcing, still not that important for understanding the problem:

```
NaseInstance = (my_odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys())
MojeInstance = ( NaseInstance[-1] )
CelaMojeInstance=my_odb.rootAssembly.instances[MojeInstance]
```

Now the crucial part:

```
# initial number = zero
MyStepNumber=0
# This is how we want our step to be called
MyStepName="Artifficial_Step"

# if such name is there already, add one
if MyStepName in my_odb.steps.keys():
    MyStepNumber=MyStepNumber+1
    MyStepName=MyStepName+str(MyStepNumber)
    print ( "it is there, now we will rather call it", MyStepName, "Now you have to reopen the odb to see it")

    # this is how we stuff data into this new step. Not important for this query
    artiffStep = my_odb.Step(name=MyStepName, description='postprocess operations', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)
    artiffFrame = artiffStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0, description='ArtifFrame')
    sessionField = artiffFrame.FieldOutput(name='Field-1', description='NEW_FIELD', field=my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'])

    # save and close to make the changes work
    my_odb.save()
    my_odb.close()

else:
    # if such name doesnt exist yet, no problem to use it
    print ( "it is not there, no problem to call it", MyStepName, "Now you have to reopen the odb")

    # rest same as in the -if- statement
    artiffStep = my_odb.Step(name=MyStepName, description='postprocess operations', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)
    artiffFrame = artiffStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0, description='ArtifFrame')
    sessionField = artiffFrame.FieldOutput(name='Field-1', description='NEW_FIELD', field=my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'])

    # save and close to make the changes work
    my_odb.save()
    my_odb.close()
```

Unfortunately, as these of you with any coding knowledge probably immediately see, if the name is not yet used, it creates the new step for the first time, calling it `"Artifficial_Step"`. If it exists and the `else` statement comes to action, it says "....we will rather call it `"Artifficial_Step1"` but then doesn't create anything new (probably as such step is already there). Instead of checking whether `Artifficial_Step1` doesn't already exist too, or `Step2`, `Step3`, `Step4`...

I guess that I need some loop to go through the names - `my_odb.steps.keys()` - and keep adding one, until it reaches a nonexistent one to create it later. May I ask for a help with such, please?

Edit:
Tried this now:

```
MyStepNumber=int(0)
MyStepName="Artifficial_Step"

while MyStepName in my_odb.steps.keys():
    MyStepNumber=MyStepNumber+1
    MyStepName=MyStepName+str(MyStepNumber)
    print ( "it is there, now we will rather call it", MyStepName, "Now you have to reopen the odb")

    artiffStep = my_odb.Step(name=MyStepName, description='postprocess operations', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)
    artiffFrame = artiffStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0, description='ArtifFrame')
    sessionField = artiffFrame.FieldOutput(name='Field-1', description='NEW_FIELD', field=my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'])

    # save and close to make the changes work
    my_odb.save()
    my_odb.close()

else:
    print ( "it is not there, no problem to call it", MyStepName, "Now you have to reopen the odb")

    artiffStep = my_odb.Step(name=MyStepName, description='postprocess operations', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)
    artiffFrame = artiffStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0, description='ArtifFrame')
    sessionField = artiffFrame.FieldOutput(name='Field-1', description='NEW_FIELD', field=my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'])

    # save and close to make the changes work
    my_odb.save()
    my_odb.close()
```

But the `while` goes on even after closing the database, therefore issuing a message that the database doesn't exist (meaning in the current GUI session) any more.

Moreover it created `Artifficial_Step`, then after reruning it created `Artifficial_Step1` and then (after closing and reruning) nothing more.

Comment: What do you mean "and then... nothing more"—and also, what happened instead?

Comment: That no other steps appeared after a rerun. The right answer is below, anyway. My boss himself helped me with that.

Comment: Good to hear. BTW, the correct spelling in "artificial" (one "f").

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Im not a native speaker so tend to struggle with these more exotic ones.

Comment: Doesn't really matter very much—you could always use something easier to spell, like "fake" or "generated". **More importantly**, you should read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) especially with respect to the naming of variables. Not doing so makes your code hard for others to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Never heard of it, will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a new step, frame, field. If it exists, add number:

MyStepNumber=int(1)
MyStepName="Artifficial_Step"+str(MyStepNumber)



while MyStepName in my_odb.steps.keys():
    MyStepNumber=MyStepNumber+1
    MyStepName="Artifficial_Step"+str(MyStepNumber)



artiffStep = my_odb.Step(name=MyStepName,      description='postprocess operations', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)
artiffFrame = artiffStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0,     description='ArtifFrame')
sessionField = artiffFrame.FieldOutput(name='Field-1',     description='NEW_FIELD', field=my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'])

# save and close to make the changes work
my_odb.save()
my_odb.close()
```